# Можно ли определить GPS координаты через WI-FI?

Tags: wifi, gps

Всем доброго времени суток!

Есть небольшое предприятие, по которому перемещаются небольшие грузовые машины. Вся площадь завода покрыта сетью wi-fi, перекрывающих друг друга (ака Круги Эйлера).

Если задать GPS-координаты всех wi-fi модулей,можно ли узнать положение грузовой машины внутри предприятия(т.е. внутри сетей wi-fi) ? Если да, то каким способом?

Может есть другие способы вычисления координат через WI-FI ?

Спасибо за внимание!

Comment: И еще вопрос в догоночку:
Необходимо определить положение машины в поле площадью километр- на-километр с точностью до метра. 
Есть в наличии GPS и GPRS + возможность установки одной вышки wi-fi

Comment: точно gps - порядка 5 метров. Для машины размером 5х3 (усредненные размеры для небольшой машины), точность 5-10 методов более чем достаточна. Но зачем там вайфай... не знаю, тем более, что в штатных условиях он километр так просто не накроет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

гугл же как то в адроидах делает такое. Значит можно.
Единственное, что нужно помнить, что сигнал вайфай не постоянный, поэтому лучше усреднять.

[Вот статья](http://habrahabr.ru/post/161195/), как человек сам написал триангуляцию.

Answer (score 3):

Я не эксперт, но думаю, можно использовать какой нибудь метод триангуляции, базирующийся на уровне сигнала от WI-FI рутеров, то есть вычислить координаты каждого рутера и потом ориентироваться по уровню сигнала от них.